# Equivalent function of %in%(from R) for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

i have two columns containing splited sentence like col("i" "love" "food") and col2 ("love","food).i want to count the matched words row wise.like here it is 2 . I want to do in python.As in R we use %in% function to do that.??

Comment: Can you explain what the exact output you want is? The best way would be to write out the R code as a full example, that way people who know both R and Python can be sure the Python code is achieving the same goal.

Comment: Output is 2 in above  case.                                                                               R code is - apply(train,1,function(x){ sum(unlist(x$query1)%in% unlist(x$query2))})

Answer (score 0):

Make sets of your word lists:

```
set1 = set(["I", "love", "food"])
set2 = set(["love", "food"])
```

And then count the number of elements in the intersection of the `set1` and `set2`:

```
num_matched = len(set1.intersection(set2))  # returns 2
```

Note that this will not count multiple matches of the same word, and in fact multiples of the same word will not even show up in `set1` or `set2`. Furthermore, sets do not guarantee an order to their elements. Hopefully this helps though.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two versions of `%in%` I've used in the past:

```
def r_in(left, right):
    return list(map(lambda x: x in right, left))
```

and

```
def r_in(left, right):
    return [x in right for x in left]
```

I think the second looks nicer and is easier to read. Note that I haven't done any benchmarks so I can't guarantee performance.

Then you can count the overlaps much like in R:

```
sum(r_in(["I", "love", "food"], ["love", "food"]))
# 2
```